# Cartesian product in gorm CreateCriteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, grails-orm

I'm trying to do the below sql statement with CreateCriteria, but I have no idea how to use same tables with different alias.
Here my domain:

```
class Analisys {

    Integer performanceStar
    Phase phase

    static belongsTo = [instrument: Instrument]

}

class Phase {

    String name
    int showOrder

    static hasMany = [category: Category]
}
class Instrument {

    Long internalId
    String name
    String description

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [ analisys: Analisys]
}
```

Here the sql statement:

```
select *
from
    analisys as a1
inner join phase as p1 on a1.phase_id = p1.id,
 analisys as a2
inner join phase as p2 on a2.phase_id = p2.id,
 analisys as a3
left join phase as p3 on a3.phase_id = p3.id
where
a1.phase_id=100
and a2.phase_id=102
and a3.phase_id=103
and a1.instrument_id = a2.instrument_id
and a1.instrument_id = a3.instrument_id
```

With CreateCriteria I start writing something like this but of course is wrong:

```
def results = Classification.createCriteria().list(max: 100, offset: 0) {

            instrument {
                analisys(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
                    eq("phase.id", 100)
                }
            }
            instrument {
                analisys(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
                    eq("phase.id", 102)
                }
            }
            instrument {

                analisys(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
                    eq("phase.id", 103)
                }
            }

        }
```

With HQL I am able to do it, using what I wrote below, but still don't understand how do it through Criteria, and now not even sure it's possible:

```
Analisys.executeQuery(" from Analisys as a1, Analisys as a2, Analisys as a3 
where a1.phase.id=100 and a2.phase.id=102 and a3.phase.id=103 
and a1.instrument.id = a2.instrument.id and a1.instrument.id = a3.instrument.id ")
```

I found an interesting article that can help who has my same problems:

[How and When to Use Various GORM Querying Options](http://tatiyants.com/how-and-when-to-use-various-gorm-querying-options/)

Comment: Please include the entity mapping, as that could shed some light on how best to accomplish what you ask.

Comment: add the domain explanation, hopefully is enough

Comment: You haven't provided the `Instrument` domain class, it's hard to get the whole picture as it is now.

Comment: sorry my bad, now updated